# Please explain to me this inequality

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In this inequality
$$m(b-a)\le \int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \le M(b-a)$$

what do $m(b-a)$ and $M(b-a)$ represent?

Comment: I would assume $m$ times the number $b-a$ and $M$ times the number $b-a$, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Generally in the context of $m(b-a) \le \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx \le M(b-a)$, we mean that for an interval $[a,b]$,
\begin{align*}
m &= \min_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)\\
M &= \max_{x\in [a,b]}f(x).
\end{align*}
So, because we know that $$m \le f(x) \le M \quad\text{for}\quad x\in [a,b],$$
it follows that
\begin{align*}
&\int_{a}^{b}m\,dx \le \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx \le \int_{a}^{b}M\,dx\\
\implies & m(b-a) \le \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx \le M(b-a).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much, By the way, since I am a new user of stack exchange, could you explain how you add mathematical symbols in an answer/question.

Comment: @YejatKrishna Take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) reference for using MathJax.